# Text following a graphic and blank space; a wrap around suggestion

Tags: discussion, images

An image whose height is more than its width, has a blank space to its right with a text following below them.

Can we wrap text around the image and upwards to shorten the posting by filling up the blank space?

Comment: I notice that you posted a [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239905) for this on Meta Stack Exchange about two years ago.

Comment: Yes,posted an ellipse image too high compared to width,,, reminding about the same.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because per-site metas aren't meant to be a way to get around closures on the global meta.

Comment: Yes, please vote to close it as of now..

Answer (score 3):

There is no support for doing this at the moment. I do not think it is very important for our site, and I think it would be hard to get it right.

Anyway, there was once a feature request by one of the founders of SE no less, still it got declined by another founder. See this post for reference:

[Can we get a way to wrap text around images?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99573/can-we-get-a-way-to-wrap-text-around-images)

Comment: Looks like " desirable though not essential " category, postponed even if easy to implement.